# Office 365 : Can't Use IE localStorage in Excel 2016

Tags: internet-explorer, local-storage, office365, office-js, excel-2016

I am trying to add one add-in for Office 365 which is using localStorage for pass value from functionfile.html to home.js.
its successfully work in Mac OS, iPad and Windows with all browser IE, Firefox, safari and chrome
but it is not working in desktop base Excel 2016

I can't read value of browser localStorage using Excel 2016

**Functionfile.HTML**

```
 <script>
    function FunctionFileHTMLScript(event) {
        localStorage.setItem("TOBUpdates", "Test");
    }
</script>
```

**Home.js**

```
function HomeJSRead() 
{
    setInterval(function () {
        var TOBUpdateString = localStorage.getItem("TOBUpdates");
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Home.html**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jmsajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Guys, Please don't hesitate to ask any type of question regarding this problem. If anybody has any suggestions then plz post

Comment: What error are you seeing?  I just did a small test on my end and I was able to successfully set localStorage on the function file and then read that on home (on a taskpane).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment

Comment: It's not showing any error in console, can I see your sample code? I did same that Home.html load first with Home.js file and set one loop which is continuously read localStorage value and set it in Taskpane.  I am updating localStorage value in Functionfile.html using contextmenu but I can't see updated value in Taskpane. same code working fine in online but not in Excel 2016 windows

Comment: Did you find a sollution for this? I am having the same issue now

Comment: No not yet.....